# Pb converting a list of pandas.Series into a numpy array of pandas.Series

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I would like to convert a list of `pandas.Series` into a numpy array of `pandas.Series`. But when I call the array constructor, it also converting my Series.

```
>>> l = [Series([1,2,3]),Series([4,5,6])]
>>> np.array(l)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

My list is small (~10 elements), so for [performances issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212777/python-pandas-small-series-performances?noredirect=1#comment33725521_22212777) I would like to avoid to create a pandas.DataFrame.
Is there an easy workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: surely creating the Series is pretty expensive too (is it that much better than a DataFrame?) It's really not clear why you want to do this (why not just use numpy proper?).

Comment: I m recording some real time measurement of about n (~20) variables. At each record, I'm calculating a rolling_moment for a subset of m (could be 1 to 20, different at each iteration) variable, and compare these data. At the moment, I'm writing the real time data in a dataframe (index size is nb of expected measure,column size is 20) , select the m intruments I need, and store rolling_moment(myDf.iloc[Ai:Bi]) in a array (Ai:Bi is different for each element of m). What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

You should set the `dtype` of the array when you assign it:

```
l = [pd.Series([1,2,3]),pd.Series([4,5,6])]
np.array(l, dtype=pd.Series)
```

Though it is raises the question: why do you want an ndarray of series, and not an ndarray of the contents of the series?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to use later on,on some of those Series, a rolling_moment function, which to my knowledge, exist only in Pandas.

Comment: Don't thank me too fast! On second inspection, it may not work. But you might want to just keep the series objects in a python list, in that case.

Comment: Well..thanks for trying, but it's not working indeed. Unfortunately, I really need a np.array

Comment: If the aim is to convert to Numpy-array representation the you can see [pandas.Series.as_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.as_matrix.html) or [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values)